# Linear Layout does't fit in xhdpi and xxhdpi, can give me advice for layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

i use LinearLayout, and does't fit in xhdpi and xxhdpi, like this.

**on hdpi**

[image: image1]

**on xhdpi, xxhdpi:**

[image: image2]

i use `LinearLayout` like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_gradien_menu"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Recommendation"
        android:textColor="@color/font"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/frame"
        android:textColor="@color/font"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/frame_mtb_roadbike" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ct"
            android:textColor="@color/font"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_focused"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="80 cm"
            android:textColor="@color/dec_font"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/adtional"
        android:textColor="@color/font"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/font"
        android:textSize="11sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/font" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/crank"
        android:textColor="@color/font"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/crank_img" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/crank_dec"
            android:textColor="@color/font"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_focused"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="80 cm"
            android:textColor="@color/dec_font"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_focused"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="80 cm"
            android:textColor="@color/dec_font"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_note"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/disclaimer"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/disclaimer_desc"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</LinearLayout>

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_starover"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_menu"
        android:text="@string/again"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

can give me advice for layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a comment: don't use `fill_parent` as it has been deprecated.  Instead, you should always use `match_parent`.

Summary: 
You need to use `layout_weight` attributes on your widgets to distribute unallocated space in your layout.  This will stretch the widgets to fill the screen along one axis (depending on the orientation of the linear layout that contains them).

Long Answer:

The problem with your layout is that you are using `wrap_content` for the height and width of many of your widgets.  This will cause the widget to be sized according to its "natural" size, which generally means big enough to fit the content, plus some extra pixels for padding and margins based on the style.  Widgets that are set to wrap content do not stretch or shrink based on the screen size.  They will always tend to gravitate to the top left of the parent container.

It is also important to note that, even if you set the parent container to `match_parent`, the widgets that it contains will not automatically fill the container.  You can, for example, create the following:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the button will float on the left side of the screen, even though the parent layout is set to match the width of the screen.

If you want widgets to stretch to fill what would otherwise be empty space on the screen in a linear layout, you have one great option: `layout_weight`.

When Android sizes a widget in a linear layout it makes two passes.  In the first pass, it uses the `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes.  If these are set to `wrap_content` the widget is set to its "natural" size in this first pass.

In the second pass, it looks at the widget's `layout_weight` attribute.  Any remaining pixels are allocated to all of the widgets based on their weights.  A widget that doesn't specify a weight at all doesn't get any of the pixels.  Widgets that do specify a weight get pixels in proportion to their weight (e.g. a widget with a weight of 2 gets twice as many as a widget with a weight of 1).  In this way ALL of the unallocated pixels in one dimension may be distributed across your widgets in whatever why that you'd like.  Want them all to go to one widget?  Give it a weight of 1 and don't give a weight to any of the other widgets.  Want to split the space equally across all widgets?  Give them all a weight of 1.

It is important to note that the weight will only distribute pixels along one axis: for horizontal linear layouts this is the X axis, and for vertical linear layouts this is the Y axis.

Answer (score -2):

You want the layout to be automatically streched? Have you considered using relativelayout as the root?

Comment: What is the difference between `linear` and `relative` in his case?

Comment: @Anson getting crushed even more on small screen

Comment: In the linearlayout, all the childrens are displayed from the beginning one after the other, according to the margin defined. In the relativelayout, if we only set the order, the top margin of first child, and the bottom margin of the last child. The other margins are automatically stretched to fit into different screen sizes.

Comment: Could you show the log for the crush? Is it because your layout is larger than the screen? If that is the case, consider the scrollview.

Comment: anything from the log? It is hard to tell what causes the crush without logcat output

Comment: how is that an answer?

Comment: A relative layout does not "automatically stretch" widgets.  What it does is place them in absolute positions (e.g. the top left corner, or the bottom center of the screen).  The widgets will remain anchored there regardless of screen size, but won't automatically stretch to fill space: there will just be more space between them on larger screens (and they may even overlap on smaller screens).

Comment: sorry guys. I have not been doing Android for long and cannot remember XML exactly now...

Comment: @BobbyStJacques It really depends on whether you want to stretch those views or you want to stretch the margins.

Comment: Which is exactly what I said.  Given the screenshots of the layout posted, it does not look like this layout was designed with gaps between the widgets in mind.  So switching from a LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout would not be a solution (unless introducing empty space between the widgets is the desired result, which would break the aesthetics of the layout).  That being said, simply swapping a LinearLayout for a RelativeLayout wouldn't be nearly enough to fix what's wrong.